# Use select distinct in JPQL and retrieve all columns

Tags: java, jpa, select, distinct, jpql

I'm working with JPQL, I want to remove all the duplicated rows using `DISTINCT`, and at the same time retrieve all the columns in a table, I wrote something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT cl.name, cl.age 
FROM Client AS cl
WHERE cl.country='****'
```

This query returns just the two columns `name` and `age`.

Comment: Could you describe exactly what you expect? All the columns of `Client`  for a specific `country` where no `name` and `age` appear more than once, maybe?

Comment: yes, exactly that

Comment: Well, imagine you have two clients with the same name and age but a different passport number. What do you want to do in that case?

Comment: well in this case passport number is not important for me, i just eliminate one of the two clients

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have a unique `id` you could write your query to use `GROUP BY` as follows:

```sql
SELECT client FROM Client client
WHERE client.id IN (
    SELECT MIN(c.id)
    FROM Client c
    WHERE c.country='****'
    GROUP BY c.name, c.age
)
```

You should not retrieve all the fields of `Client` because you should not select non-aggregated fields.

Comment: my question was to SELECT Client, not DELETE from Client, but anyways this answer my question

Comment: I used `DELETE` to adjust to your comment. But accepted your edit to answer your actual question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
DELETE from Client c
Where c.name IN (SELECT DISTINCT cl.name
                 FROM Client AS cl
                 WHERE cl.country='****')
```

But pay attention to your persistence context to avoid corrupt data.

Comment: this does not work, since i need to select Client and eliminate rows that have the same name and age